# Mouse cursor flickering when placed just below the border of the tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, primeng

The mouse cursor flickers between link pointer and computer pointer when i move the mouse just below the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily solved by changing the css of the tooltip.
Just set the **Pointer events to none**.
This will work for all whether you use **Angular's/Bootstrap's/PrimeNG's/CSS** tooltips
If you use CSS
`.tooltip { pointer-events: none; }`
If you use PrimeNG(pTooltip)
`.ui-tooltip { pointer-events: none; }`
You have to just place it in the tooltip class.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - for newer versions of PrimeNG use:

```
.p-tooltip {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```